# Add KeyChain Item to KeyChain Fail with error "write permission error" on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos

create one access object to keychain item:

```
{
  + (SecAccessRef)createKeychainAccessForLabel:(NSString *)accessLabel appPahts:(NSArray *)appPaths
    {
        OSStatus err = noErr;
        SecAccessRef access=nil;

        //Create trusted application references; see SecTrustedApplications.h:
        NSMutableArray *trustedApplications = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *aPath in appPaths)
        {
            SecTrustedApplicationRef appRef = NULL;
            err = SecTrustedApplicationCreateFromPath([aPath UTF8String], &appRef);
            [trustedApplications addObject:(id)appRef];
            CFRelease(appRef);
        }

        //Create an access object:
        err = SecAccessCreate((CFStringRef)accessLabel, (CFArrayRef)trustedApplications, &access);

        if (err != noErr)
        {
            access = nil;
        }

        // the momery would be released by the invoker
        return access;
    }
}
```

create KeyChain Item:

```
{
        const char *serviceUTF8 = [serviceName UTF8String];
        const char *accountUTF8 = [account UTF8String];
        const char *passwordUTF8 = [password UTF8String];
        const char *itemLabelUTF8 = [label UTF8String];

        //Create initial access control settings for the item:
        SecAccessRef access = [self createKeychainAccessForLabel:label appPahts:appPaths];

        //Set up the attribute vector (each attribute consists of {tag, length, pointer}):
        SecKeychainAttribute attrs[] =
        {
            {kSecLabelItemAttr, strlen(itemLabelUTF8), (char *)itemLabelUTF8},
            {kSecAccountItemAttr, strlen(accountUTF8), (char *)accountUTF8},
            {kSecServiceItemAttr, strlen(serviceUTF8), (char *)serviceUTF8}
        };

        SecKeychainAttributeList attributes = {sizeof(attrs) / sizeof(attrs[0]), attrs};

        err = SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent(
                                               kSecGenericPasswordItemClass,
                                               &attributes,
                                               strlen(passwordUTF8),
                                               passwordUTF8,
                                               NULL, // use the default keychain
                                               access,
                                               &item);

        CFStringRef message = SecCopyErrorMessageString(err, NULL);
        NSLog(@"create keychain item: %@", (NSString *)message);
}
```

run those codes on os x 10.10 test version, but with error ending :create keychain item: write permission error, search this question on google and stack overflow, but nothing
 is relative,  any ideas??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is concerns OSX 10.10, which is currently at Developer Preview 2 and has not been released to the general public. Pre-Beta Operating Systems are expected to have issues. OSX 10.10 problems should be, at this time, reported to Apple and only be discussed on developer.apple.com forums.

Comment: Thank You Merlin069 for you reply,i will go to developer.apple.com forums to seek something.

Comment: @thethirdtiger  Have you solved this issue? I am also facing same Problem. Thanks in advance.